# Sum calculated from parent process and child process using fork() not correct in C

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I was hoping to get some help about the following issue.
So, in the child process I get a value of 7 which is confirmed the printf statement after the for loop.
The issue however is that after writing the value of the sum of the child process to partial_sum in the parent process, I receive a different value of 32_768. and thus result at the end is NOT equal to 13.

Can someone help me find the issue in my code please?
Thanks in advance!

```
// question: what is the issue here???

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2};
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int start, end;
    int pid = fork();
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) return 1;

    if (pid == 0){
        start = 0;
        end = arr_size / 2;
    } else {
        start = arr_size / 2;
        end = arr_size;
    }

    // calculation:
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start ; i < end; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);

    // transferring the value;
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        if(write(fd[1], &sum, sizeof(sum)) == -1) return 1;
        close(fd[1]);
    } else {
        int partial_sum;
        close(fd[1]);
        if (read(fd[0], &partial_sum, sizeof(partial_sum)) == -1) return 2;
        close(fd[0]);
        int result = partial_sum + sum;
        printf("The final result is: %d", result);
        wait(NULL);
    }


}
```

was expecting as a result 13, but got the following output:

```
The sum is: 7
The sum is: 6
The final result is: 32774
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `pipe()` before `fork()`? In any case, running this in a debugger should have made it obvious that the communication between parent and child doesn't work.

Comment: Currently, the parent and child both create their own pipes. Even though the pipe in the the parent and child will use the same file descriptor numbers, they are not the same pipe because they have different *open file descriptions*. Nothing writes to the "write" end of the parent's pipe, and nothing reads from the "read" end of the child's pipe.

Comment: Note that the error test on read and write should be `!= sizeof(variable)` rather than `== -1`.  You can get zero bytes read, indicating EOF, and short writes are a problem.  For read, you probably need to capture the value in a variable so you an distinguish between an error and EOF.

Answer (score 2):

When `pipe` is called after `fork`, it opens a separate pipe in the current process, so you get one pipe in the parent and a different pipe in the child.

Move the call to `pipe` before the call to `fork`. This will create one pipe that will be shared when the `fork` duplicates the process.

Additionally, do not test `read` and `write` return values only by comparing them to −1. They may return other values, including zero for end-of-file or a number between zero and the requested number of bytes. To determine whether a read or write succeeded completely, compare the return value to the requested number of bytes. (And then perform further comparisons if you wish to distinguish the failing cases.) Doing this would have revealed the read was not working.